# git push fatal: Not a git repository: '.'

Tags: git

I can not understand, why 'fatal' is here? And really all commits are pushed.

```
oleg@shoom-gnome:(master)~/workspace/S4$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 280 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://account@host/var/git/S4
   79ea0f2..6e8a193  master -> master
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if `/var/git/S4` on the remote *is* a git repository, then, perhaps, it's something happening in the hook script?

And, duplicating my comment to kmarsh's answer I've just upvoted: I'd recommend `account@host:/var/git/S4` instead of url-like form for ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
ssh://account@host/var/git/S4
```

with

```
ssh://account@host//var/git/S4
```

To get the full path instead of one relative to account's home dir.

Comment: uh... now I realized it looks weird. I'd suggest `account@host:/var/git/S4` then instead of url-like form. The problem is, should git have gone this far if it was a wrong directory?